# How to set multiple language on setup time in radio button . See more: C#

Tags: c#

I am using a localization in my project, But my question is when user install a project
they choose a either English or Marathi language from the radio button option in set up time and my whole project run on that particular language only?
How to set this on set up time?

Comment: How are you localizing your application?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create two files (or static arrays/lists of strings, but this is not recommended as the application will keep both ready in RAM, and this can take up quite some memory if the application contains a lot of text) and then a static List of type string.

Whenever the user selects an option, you'll have to make your application load the appropriate file (by calling List.Add for each row of your file, depending on how you built it).

There is a downside, obviously: Instead of just assigning a string to a control, you'll have to add it to the lang file, and when creating said control, you'll need to pass it the corresponding element in your list.

I think that this is the best option, otherwise you could create two lists containing both languages when the application starts, and dispose of the unused one after the user applies the new configuration.

Comment: I´ve got a form which maximum size is 300x300 pixels.
It can be resized and maximized. The problem:
 
If the user sets the window state to maximized, the forms location
is set to 0,0. Changing the Location property doesn´t help.
 
Is it possible to center it on the screen even if maximized?
And if yes, how is it done?